# Scons not passing CCFLAGS to gcc

Tags: python, gcc, scons

I am trying to build a simple GTK C application (specifically a MATE applet) using Scons, since I was getting nowhere with autotools.

In my SConstruct file, I have this:

```
env = Environment(tools=['default', 'scanreplace'], toolpath=['tools'])

env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0')
env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0')
env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs libmatepanelapplet-3.0')
```

which is supposed to locate the correct directories etc. Running pkg-config in a terminal works fine, e.g.:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

However when I run scons, this is part of the output:

```
gcc -o .build/resource-applet -pthread src/resource-applet.h .build/src/resource-applet.o -lmate-panel-applet-3 -lmateconf-2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
src/resource-applet.h:22:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

There are no  -I flags anywhere, so as I understand it, gcc can't find the header files.

So why is scons not giving gcc the -I flags, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [ParseFlags()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1861.html) function for the '-I' paths as it appears from the SCons documentation that the [ParseConfig()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1898.html) function is intended mainly for library detection.

To debug what you have in your SConscript, you could do something like the following:

```
def populateEnv(env, packageName, debug=False):
    d = env.ParseFlags('!pkg-config --cflags --libs %s' % packageName)
    if debug:
        # print the dictionary

    if debug:
        # print the CCFLAGS, LIBPATH, and CPPPATH before calling MergeFlags()

    env.MergeFlags(d)

    if debug:
        # print the CCFLAGS, LIBPATH, and CPPPATH after calling MergeFlags()

    env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs %s' % packageName)

    if debug:
        # print the CCFLAGS, LIBPATH, and CPPPATH after calling ParseConfig()

...    
populateEnv(env, 'glib-2.0', True)
populateEnv(env, 'libmatepanelapplet-3.0', True)
populateEnv(env, 'gtk+-2.0', True)
...
```

Comment: Now this is weird. This seems to fix the GTK problem, but a similar problem pops up. Here is my github repo where you can find the whole thing: https://github.com/geniass/mate-resource-applet. So ParseFlags works fine, the dictionary contains all the right paths, but after I call MergeFlags, some of the paths disappear, causing more errors. Output here: http://pastebin.com/bvLLvYzv

Comment: Its hard to tell since the output in the pastebin link doesnt correspond with the print statements in the SCons scripts in your github link. I wonder if the merge_dols() function is really necessary, since SCons should do that for you. Try testing it again with using that function.

Comment: @geniass, oops, I made a typo, and I cant edit it now.  I meant to say Try testing it again without using that function.

Comment: I did try that, and for some reason the libmatepanel includes were being removed from the dictionary. THe reason is because the dictionary is actually a dictionary of lists, hence the merge_dol function. I can still try calling MergeFlags three times.

Comment: Ok I am now using MergeFlags instead, and it gets a bit further. Here's the new build output: http://pastebin.com/Y0FMYNiX
Also it wasn't compiling before because I left out main.c. That's irritating

Comment: @geniass, it does indeed look better, all that is missing now are the libraries (-l) which should be specified with the ParseConfig(). That is, you need to use both ParseFlags() and ParseConfig(). I'll update the answer with some debugging help, since it looks like what you have on github is out of sync a bit with the output.

Comment: OK I added the debugging code on github, and I get the same result as you (no libraries in the dictionary). BTW I got it working with cmake which is on the cmake branch on github

Comment: I found that parseFlags puts libraries in LIBS (of course), so giving the Program builder the argument `LIBS=env['LIBS']` solves the problem. But now I have a new error `undefined reference to symbol 'g_type_check_instance_cast'` which I also got with cmake, but the fix involved some obscure cmake-specific stuff. So now I have no idea what to do.

Comment: @geniass, what was the cmake fix?

Comment: Cmake uses a file called Find[whatever library].cmake to find libraries, and I was getting this error with a non-standard cmake file. Turns out KDE'S version of this file fixed it, so I actually have no idea what the fix was.

Comment: @geniass, if you can get the lib paths (-L) and libs (-l) from the cmake output, then you can just add them by hand to the SCons scripts.